# Access servlet init parameters from filter

Tags: initialization, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0, init-parameters

I have a servlet like this:

```
@WebServlet("/a/path")
@WebInitParam(name="name", value="name_value")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
//...
```

On this servlet I have put a filter:

```
@WebFilter(dispatcherTypes = { DispatcherType.REQUEST }, urlPatterns = { "/a/*" })
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
//...
       HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
       //problem comes here
       System.out.println(req.getServletContext().getInitParameter("name"));
//...
}
```

The problem is, that even if I set the @WebInitParameter in *MyServlet*, the programs prints out a null string (see the commented line *//problem comes here* in *MyFilter*). I verified and saw that *init()* method from servlet is executed before of *doFilter()*. 
So can anyone light me on this issue? Why the *initParameter* "name" is null, if it is set up to a value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think WebInitParam is defining init parameters for servlet and not for whole application context, so if you want acces parameters through ServletContext object, then define context params in you web.xml deployment descriptor.

Comment: and is possible to access my servlet's ServletConfig from Filter?

Comment: I dont think so, maybe is better option use filter init parameters then servlet init parameters.